# Must remove setTimeout functions in test file

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-hooks, jestjs

Although the unit test currently passes using the "setTimeout" function. I need to rid of the "setTimeout" function in a test file, however this is proving difficult. Ive tried using "waitForElement", however to no avail, Please any suggestions?
"waitFor" is not available in the React test libraries.

**Testing libraries:**

```
"@testing-library/react": "9.4.0",
"@testing-library/react-hooks": "5.0.3",
```

**Function/Method**

```
export const useFilters = () => {
  const filters = useFilters();
  const { filtersData, products, loading, error } = useCatalogue({ filters });

  const { data: pageContent } = usePageContent({
    location: pageKeys.GRID_VIEW
  });

  const { data: content } = usePagePod({
    location: pageKeys.GRID_VIEW,
    podKey: podKeys.GRID_VIEW_FILTERS
  });

  const filterIcons = useFilterIcons(content);
  const filterContent = useFilterContent(content);

  const colourFilterOptions = useColourFilterOptions(filtersData);

  const newFilters = useMemo(
    () => mapFilterOptions(filters, filtersData, colourFilterOptions, filterIcons),
    [products]
  );

  return {
    products,
    filters: newFilters,
    filterContent,
    pageContent,
    error,
    loading
  };
};
```

**Jest unit test:**

```
 describe('filters onClick', () => {
    it.only('should update the colour filter and call the hook again with colour selection when the colour onClick function is called', async () => {

      const { result } = renderHook(useFilters);

      expect(getOption(result.current.filters.colours, 'Green').selected).toBeFalse();

      act(() => {
        getOption(result.current.filters.colours, 'Green').onClick('Green');
      });

      setTimeout(
        () => expect(getOption(result.current.filters.colours, 'Green').selected).toBeTrue(),
        100
      );

});
```

Comment: Use `waitFor` instead?

Comment: Hi Konrad, unfortunately i get "TypeError: (0 , _react.waitFor) is not a function"... Would you know which version of the '@testing-library/react' library waitFor is available?

Answer (score 0):

please update your library @testing-library/react to latest version.

`npm i @testing-library/react@latest`

Answer (score 0):

"@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",

```
import { waitFor, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('filters onClick', () => {
    it.only('should update the colour filter and call the hook again with colour selection when the colour onClick function is called', async () => {

      const { result } = renderHook(useFilters);

      expect(getOption(result.current.filters.colours, 'Green').selected).toBeFalse();

      act(() => {
        getOption(result.current.filters.colours, 'Green').onClick('Green');
      });

      await waitFor(() => {
       expect(getOption(result.current.filters.colours, 'Green').selected).toBeTrue();
      });
});
```